# display average of two rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
studentname I II
Vivek Johari 30 20
Chandra Singh 30 20
Avinash Dubey 30 25
Pankaj Kumar 33 29
```

I have a table named student with details as above. I want to find the average of column I and II and display it on a new column using pivot. Please help me to solve this using pivot..
May I use any sub query to solve this using pivot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your questions is not specific enough.
Do you want the total average of both columns? just do

```
select avg (I), avg(II)
from your_table
```

if you want just one value, you can do:

```
select (avg (I) + avg(II))/2
from your_table
```